# Retrofit 2.0 - Custom CallAdapterFactory - Callbacks not happening on MainThread

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm in the process of migrating my Android app to Retrofit 2.0. I had a custom ErrorHandler extending `RetrofitError` so I could react to different Http errors.

Now I understand I must create a custom `CallAdapterFactory`. I used the sample `ErrorHandlingCallAdapter` provided [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/ErrorHandlingCallAdapter.java).

My resulting `CallAdapter` is pretty much the same code, but if needed I could also post my code.

What's happening is that when I use this `CallAdapterFactory`, callbacks are not happening on the MainThread. I get `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException` when trying to update the UI (which I always need to). I also don't want to always wrap my code with runOnUIThread in my callbacks.

I don't know if this helps, but when I log `Thread.currentThread().getName()` in my callbacks, it returns OkHttp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up passing an executor to my CallAdapter.Factory:

```
public static class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void execute(@NonNull Runnable r) {
        handler.post(r);
    }
}
```

...

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(new ErrorHandlingCallAdapter.ErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory(new MainThreadExecutor()))
```

and wrapping the callback in:

```
callbackExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
});
```

I inspired myself from [this](https://gist.github.com/rahulgautam/25c72ffcac70dacb87bd#file-errorhandlingexecutorcalladapterfactory-java).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new executor, you can use retrofit's :

```
public AuthCall adapt(Call call) {
    return new CustomCall(call, statuses, retrofit.callbackExecutor());
}
```

keep a reference of it in your adapted calls, and then use it within your callback:

```
customCall.enqueue(new Callback() {
    executor.execute(...
```